# Want to import JSON data into my local storage

Tags: json

I am trying to store my JSON data into my local storage. I am not able to find the way to do. Please assist me if anyone has any idea about it.This is my JSON data.**http://67.209.121.4/products.json**. Any help is highly appreciated.Thanks in advance!

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/707761/is-there-a-way-to-get-curl-output-into-a-file

Comment: @Jacob I think you are telling him that his post is off-topic but instead you could help him to write better questions. This would be more helpful. I don't want to offend you. But you are right it's off-topic because of missing detail.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know the localStorage only stores key/value pairs. Therefore first stringify you JSON and then store it. To read it you need to get the string and then parse it back. See code:

```js
var jn = {
      "test": {
          "test": 1,
          "testx": 2,
          "xtest": {
              "x": 1,
              "y": 2
          },
          "test2": 1
      },
      "xx":{
          "x":2,
          "y": 3,
          "z": [1,2,3]
      }
  };

  localStorage.setItem("myData", JSON.stringify(jn));
  var data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("myData"));
  console.log(data);
```

You need to run that code inside of an HTML-File to run, because of sandboxing.

Comment: how can I do the above file http://67.209.121.4/products.json using javascript? Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: You should put the puzzle parts together and solve it. Both answers provided and combined are the solution. It seems like you want somebody else to solve your problem, but thats not exactly what stackoverflow is for. It's to help people with concrete problems not free them from thinking or learning.

Answer (score 0):

If you intend on using Node.js to accomplish this task, you may want to take a look at the [request](https://npmjs.org/package/request) and [fs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fs) modules on npm.

Other than that, this code should be approximately what you are looking for:

```
var request = require("request")
var fs = require("fs")

// This is your URL
var url = "http://67.209.121.4/products.json"

// This is the code for accessing and storing the data using request
request({
    url: url,
    json: true
}, function (error, response, body) {

    // This is the part where you store your data locally using fs
    if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {
        var content = JSON.stringify(body);
        fs.writeFile("./content.json", content, 'utf8', function (err) {
            if (err) {
                return console.log(err);
            }

            console.log("The file was saved!");
        }); 
    }

})
```

Remember to use the command `npm install fs && npm install request` before you attempt to execute this code in Node.js.

Comment: Thank you for your code. But how can I do this by using JavaScript code. Your help is highly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Pure javascript solution. If you know javascript and if you are able to understand it: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX/Getting_Started